# I can't Update Records in sqlite for Iphone programming

Tags: iphone

```
-(void)updateData:(NSInteger)ind
{

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {   
        NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE User SET UserName=?,FullName=?,Email=? WHERE UserId=?;"];
        const char *sql = [sqlStr UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"DatabaseNotAvailable", @"") message:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_errmsg(db)]
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];   
            [alert release];
            //NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }


        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [tmpun UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [tmpfn UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [tmpem UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Records" message:@"Record Not inserted" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert=nil;
        }
        else 
        {
           UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Records"   message:@"Record Updated" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert=nil;
        }

        sqlite3_reset(statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

  sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

I am trying to Update my selected record. the statement is executed properly but record is not updated into databse. ind=INdex of selected record. 
Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: How do you set up your database, i mean what is databasePath (Path to database in bundle or document directory) ?

Comment: dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);                                       docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

 // Build the path to the database file
 databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"UserData.sqlite"]];
 
 NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
this is how i load my database file.  Thank's for your reply.

Comment: you already asked a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890315/problem-with-inserting-data-into-a-table now I am sure if you take a hint from that you can fix this problem on your own. A quick question here is as to Where do you set four values that you mention in the update query because I see only three values being bound to the statement where is the UserId being set. Are you missing with that ?

Comment: hey Mr. Rahul I solved my query and i really appreciate your help. because of you i can solve my problem very well.

Comment: @Sam : You should add an answer with a description of your solution and accept it to close the question.